# Transfer Files To VPS Using FTP

Tags: ftp, vps

I Just Got A Free VPS From Upcloud.com

It has VNC Preinstalled, 2 GB Ram, 1 Core Cpu.

I Just Installed PHP and mySQL.

My Vps Ip

```
http://83.136.252.156/
```

How do I upload with ftp files to:

```
/var/www
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Nooooo! 
Don't use that protocol left over from the 70th! It is a nightmare for all firewall administrators.

Use the ssh server instead which you undoubtedly already used for other purposes: 
the ssh server offers sub protocols, namely scp and sftp. 
You can use sftp from the command line, many modern ftp clients also support this more advanced protocol too. And you don't have to install and configure an additional ftp server which can be painful. And you get strong encryption of your credentials as well.

There are many manuals out there in the internet. 
Create yourself a key (much more safe and convenient than using passwords) and go!

Comment: Ah, I see you removed the references to the ftp protocol from your question :-) Anyway: sftp is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

upload your files through ftp client called 'Filezilla' or if you have upload facility through control panel itself then well upload from their itself. Create FTP from your control panel and Download [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and install it locally on your system and upload by connecting to your server using following details like Host, Username, Password and Port.

But i suggest not to go with free hosting services where they are used one and would have changes to spam access more. Anyhow if your looking for some best and [cheap vps hosting](http://tws.trijit.in/vps-hosting/) services than will suggest for my datacenter provider, which is TRIJIT.